# Sequel: How to use group and count

Tags: ruby, count, group-by, sequel

Simply put, how can I do this query using [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/)?

```
select a.id, count(t.id)
from albums a
right join tracks t on t.album_id = a.id
group by a.id
```

Answer (score 8):

```
DB[:albums___a].
  right_join(:tracks___t, :album_id=>:id).
  select_group(:a__id).
  select_more{count(:t__id)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the left join finds a track ID for each album ID.  Solutions:

`right join`

subquery of sums, assuming sequel supports that: `left join (select album_id, count(album_id) as count from tracks group by album_id) t on`

a strait up `from albums a, tracks t where t.album_id=a.id` instead of the join.

Comment: You're right about the right join, but I was talking about the Sequel ruby framework, not plain SQL. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I've edited the question to replace the inner join by a right join.

Comment: *facepalm*  ... not sure then.