# Sequel -- How To Construct This Query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I have a `users` table, which has a one-to-many relationship with a `user_purchases` table via the foreign key `user_id`.  That is, each user can make many purchases (or may have none, in which case he will have no entries in the user_purchases table).

`user_purchases` has only one other field that is of interest here, which is `purchase_date`.

I am trying to write a Sequel ORM statement that will return a dataset with the following columns:

- user_id
- date of the users SECOND purchase, if it exists

So users who have not made at least 2 purchases will not appear in this dataset.  What is the best way to write this Sequel statement?

**Please note I am looking for a dataset with ALL users returned who have >= 2 purchases**

Thanks!

### EDIT FOR CLARITY

Here is a similar statement I wrote to get users and their first purchase date (as opposed to 2nd purchase date, which I am asking for help with in the current post):

```rb
   DB[:users].join(:user_purchases, :user_id => :id)
              .select{[:user_id, min(:purchase_date)]}
              .group(:user_id)
```

Comment: Why don't you show us the code and models you're using to generate the query? Describing it doesn't help without the code itself.

Comment: @theTinMan, Hey, you should have all the info you need to answer the question.  I edited the OP to clarify what I'm asking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be worried about the dates, just the counts so

```
DB[:user_purchases].group_and_count(:user_id).having(:count > 1).all
```

will return a list of user_ids and counts where the count (of purchases) is >= 2. Something like

```
[{:count=>2, :user_id=>1}, {:count=>7, :user_id=>2}, {:count=>2, :user_id=>3}, ...]
```

If you want to get the users with that, the easiest way with Sequel is probably to extract just the list of user_ids and feed that back into another query:

```
DB[:users].where(:id => DB[:user_purchases].group_and_count(:user_id).
    having(:count > 1).all.map{|row| row[:user_id]}).all
```

---

**Edit:**

I felt like there should be a more succinct way and then I saw this answer (from Sequel author Jeremy Evans) to another question using `select_group` and `select_more` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10886982/131226

This should do it without the subselect:

```
DB[:users].
  left_join(:user_purchases, :user_id=>:id).
  select_group(:id).
  select_more{count(:purchase_date).as(:purchase_count)}.
  having(:purchase_count > 1)
```

It generates this SQL

```
SELECT `id`, count(`purchase_date`) AS 'purchase_count' 
FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `user_purchases` 
ON (`user_purchases`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`) 
GROUP BY `id` HAVING (`purchase_count` > 1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this could be the SQL query that you need:

```
SELECT u.id, up1.purchase_date FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_purchases up1 ON u.id = up1.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_purchases up2 ON u.id = up2.user_id AND up2.purchase_date < up1.purchase_date
GROUP BY u.id, up1.purchase_date
HAVING COUNT(up2.purchase_date) = 1;
```

Try converting that to sequel, if you don't get any better answers.

Answer (score 0):

The date of the user's second purchase would be the second row retrieved if you do an `order_by(:purchase_date)` as part of your query.

To access that, do a `limit(2)` to constrain the query to two results then take the `[-1]` (or `last`) one. So, if you're not using models and are working with datasets only, and know the `user_id` you're interested in, your (untested) query would be:

```
DB[:user_purchases].where(:user_id => user_id).order_by(:user_purchases__purchase_date).limit(2)[-1]
```

Here's some output from Sequel's console:

```
DB[:user_purchases].where(:user_id => 1).order_by(:purchase_date).limit(2).sql
=> "SELECT * FROM user_purchases WHERE (user_id = 1) ORDER BY purchase_date LIMIT 2"
```

Add the appropriate `select` clause:

```
.select(:user_id, :purchase_date)
```

and you should be done:

```
DB[:user_purchases].select(:user_id, :purchase_date).where(:user_id => 1).order_by(:purchase_date).limit(2).sql
=> "SELECT user_id, purchase_date FROM user_purchases WHERE (user_id = 1) ORDER BY purchase_date LIMIT 2"
```

Comment: If i follow you, this would be a solution for finding a specific user's 2nd purchase date, given that user's user_id, correct?  What I am looking for is the complete dataset of all user's who have made >= 2 purchases.

Comment: Ah. That's a different question and isn't clear in the question at all. "...date of the users SECOND purchase, if it exists..."

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited the OP again to clarify that point